# Dynamics WEB API returns on post -StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, http-post, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to create **a lead in CRM** from via **web api** , but its throwing unauthorized access error. I am able to login to CRM but from Web Api , It's throwing error
Below is my code

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credentials })
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://*******.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/api/data/v8.2/")
        };
 Entity lead1 = new Entity();
           lead1["firstname"] = "TestFirstName";
           lead1["lastname"] = "TestLastName";
           lead1["emailaddress1"] = "%%%%%%%%%";
           lead1["companyname"] = "&&&&&&";



            string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(lead1).ToString();

            HttpRequestMessage request = null;

            try
            {

            request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "leads");
            request.Content = new StringContent(output); 
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.SendAsync(request);

            response.Wait();       
            if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //retrievedContact1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(rep    .Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
```

Comment: Why not use the SDK ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx

Comment: link you posted uses soap end point. I wanted to use web API. I achieved it. We need to use OAuth authentication and Then pass access token to access CRM Web Api